# Can someone explain the construction of 'siempre lo arruina todo'?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, objetos-directos

What purpose is served by 'lo' in the sentence:

> Siempre lo arruina todo | She always ruins everything

I'm not understanding the construction of this sentence. The 'lo' seems to be redundant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It *is* redundant, but it's not wrong. It's also not compulsory to include it there. You could say, correctly:

> *Siempre arruina todo.*

For all practical matters this means the same as with *lo* (see below, though, for details).

This redundant neutral pronoun is very often found in sentences with *todo*. It says [here](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Lo%20pronombre%20neutro.htm), especifically, that **"the unstressed pronoun *lo* anticipates the direct complement (= object) when it is after the verb, or when it is the nominal predicate of a copulative sentence."** That is, the presence of *todo* as the direct object causes *lo* to appear, and that also happens when *todo* is part of a copulative predicate (e.g. when the subject is followed by the verb *ser* or *estar* plus *todo*). For example:

1. Where *todo* is the direct object:

   - *Lo sabe todo.*
   - *El oro lo puede todo.*
   - *Este niño todo lo destroza.*
   - *Este niño lo destroza todo.*
   - *Quiero saberlo todo.*
   - *Lo sé ya todo.*
   - *Lo había leído todo ya.*
2. Where *todo* is part of a copulative predicate:

   - *Para mí lo eres todo.*
   - *El dinero lo era todo para él.*
   - *Para él todo era materia y la materia lo era todo.*

Though this reference text says *lo* must appear in these cases, for the most part that's not correct: it does appear very often, but is not compulsory. It needs to appear only in some sentences where the reference could be ambiguous, because *lo... todo* often means "all of it" while *todo* by itself means "everything". So for example:

- *Lo leí todo.* = "I read all of it."
- *Leí todo.* = "I read everything."

This nuance is very subtle, though, and may not even be perceived by many native speakers.

Comment: Thank you! The final two bullet points in your answer has made things clear to me.